# How to turn on Network Discovery and Share between computers with Samba

Tags: networking, windows, samba

I have an Ubuntu server. 
Accessing the server from Windows clients works fine.

But the server is not listed among the available PCs on Windows client's Network overview.
For windows machines it would be the **Network Discovery** feature.

How can I make my Samba server visible on the network?

Windows version is Windows 7.
The Workgroup in `smb.conf` is the same as in Windows.

Comment: I added the Edit, thnx for the answer!

Comment: Ah, after explicitely adding the workgroup to my share-entry in smb.conf it worked, thnx! Before I had the workgroup in the global settings only!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To share resources (File Sharing) between 2 or more computers on the same LAN you need Samba which by default comes with Network discovery (After having Samba installed) activated. It will work for your local network but you need to remember to set the **workgroup** to the one the network is using.

To install Samba, first you either have to "Share a folder", I recommend sharing anything inside your home folder so it is less trouble because of permissions, this can be a folder in your desktop for example. You can share it by right clicking the folder and selecting Sharing, Ubuntu will guide you through a couple of Sharing questions that involve installing Samba and setting the correct permissions.

The other way to install samba is by literally installing samba ;). Either with **Software Center** or in the terminal typing the following: `sudo apt-get install samba` <-- Didn't see that one coming did you!

Now to edit the Samba configuration and make sure you are on the **same network workgroup**. The workgroup should be the same for all machines in your LAN. This way, they can actually take advantage of the network discovery between Windows and Ubuntu or Ubuntu and Ubuntu machines.

1. Edit your `smb.conf` file: `sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`
2. Find the line in the **[Global]** secion that reads **workgroup**

   ```
   [global]

   ## Browsing/Identification ###

   # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of  
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
   ```
3. Change the value of workgroup to the one your network workgroup is using or set a new name for the workgroup you would like to be working on, for example:

   ```
   workgroup = myhomenet
   ```
4. Save the file and restart the Samba service: `sudo service smbd restart`

Enjoy the power of weird network discovery ^^

This should be enough to have an Ubuntu to Ubuntu LAN working but in cases where Windows is involved and just in case Windows does not see your Ubuntu PC, add the following to your **[Global]** section in your `smb.conf` file:

```
local master = yes
preferred master = yes
```

And of course restart your Samba service.

If still it does not see it, in Windows look for the **Advanced Sharing Settings** found in the left panel in the **Network and Sharing Center**. While in there choose the option **Enable file sharing for devices that use 40 or 56 bit encryption**. This is only an issue in Windows Vista and Above, if you have Windows XP it should work correctly.

After this, to access any other computers on the Network you can open the File Browser and select **Browse Network** :

[image]

Comment: My two Ubuntu laptops don't recognize each other at the "Enjoy the power of weird network discovery ^^" point :-(

Comment: @Antinous wait but if both are Ubuntu, why do you need advanced configuration for samba then? I mean I understand ease of use, but it should be as easy as right clicking a folder and clicking on share. This would install the basic for Samba. Can I ask what version of ubuntu you are using. To give you an idea, right now I have 3 computers using ubuntu 17.04. The router has upnp enabled and they can easily see each other. Basically the shared resources show automatically on the others .

Comment: I am running 16.04 and 16.10. upnp is also enabled on my router...

Comment: If possible, could you upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04 or install 16.04. Maybe not you but in my case, 16.10 was hell for me in too many ways. I practically jumped over it when going from 16.04 to 17.04.

Comment: Ok I upgraded my 16.10 laptop to 17.04. Now when I click "Windows Network" I get the error: "Unable to access location\n Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory". However, if I type "smb://MY.IP.ADD.RESS" then it does work !

Comment: But now I get more errors: "Operation not supported by backend" when I try to copy files :-(. I made sure to purge my old samba installations and reinstall...

Comment: This is now fixed. I had shared my Documents folder in Home, this didn't work. So I shared my Home folder instead. That worked ! :-D

Comment: @Antinous you da man!

Comment: I did a couple of things. First, I changed my `hostname` apparently both my laptops were using similar hostnames. Then I went into the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file and changed the interface my slave machine was using. `interfaces = 10.0.0.0/8 wlx1459c03f3385` where the first part is my home ip address, and the 2nd part is the name of my wifi card. After doing these things, I was able to upload and download files to my slave device. Mentioning this as it might help someone.

Comment: Didn't work for me. But @Marko's solution did.

Answer (score 5):

I just decided to fix this annoying problem. I have had it for a long time but now when I set up a new PC it was time to make it work.

1. I set my Ubuntu box as a WINS server and also added the lines from the post above to my `smb.conf`:

   ```
   wins support = yes
   local master = yes
   preferred master = yes
   ```
2. Since that didn't help, I forced my Win7 box to use the Ubuntu box as WINS server by modifying the advanced WINS settings in the IPv4 preferences of the network adapter
3. That didn't help either so I fired up Wireshark to see what was happening. I saw the Win7 box query the WINS server and I saw the response containing all computers with shares. So, why didn't they show up in Windows? I thought **Firewall**. I use the Windows firewall and in the advanced settings for that I noticed that

   ```
   File and Printer Sharing (LLMNR-UDP-In)
   ```

   is enabled for private networks but not for domain or public. I simply enabled the rule for domain and public as well.
4. Phew, my computers now show up in Windows. I suppose that there might be a way to make Win7 include the Ubuntu box and other linux machines in whatever it defines as **private network** but I will save that adventure for another day.

I hope that this might help someone.

EDIT: After enabling the firewall rule I removed the hard-coded WINS server setting in the network adapter, now when the traffic is allowed, I think that the standard negotiatioon process might work as I want it to.

Comment: Regarding your step 4: whenever you join a new wireless network on Windows it asks you whether it is a public or private network. What you've chosen is then displayed under your network settings. You need to forget the network and reconnect to change it. If you are at home you can choose private network such that network discovery isn't blocked.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is old question, it is still topic where Samba has some problems.

I was putting up Samba server and it was working properly, except my Windows 10 were not able to see my Samba server in Network places (but I was able to access it via IP address directly). The problem is in Windows Service Discovery - which is not yet implemented in Samba.

There is however [WSDD github repository](https://github.com/christgau/wsdd) which adds this functionality into your Samba server. It is written in Python with good documentation and also links to alternative projects, discussions why Samba is not working and also warns about using SMB1 protocol (which is still seen as a "fix" to this problem in some 
instructions on the internet - because it uses NetBIOS which IS impemented in Samba).

Answer (score 2):

Well I have solved it by going to add remove windows components and checked SMB1 /CIFS client and server and it worked like a charm.
I hope it helps you.

Regards

Marko

Answer (score 2):

In 2023

```
sudo apt install wsdd
```

just works.  By default it listens on all non-loopback interfaces, but you can edit /etc/default/wsdd to restrict where it listens, etc.

(Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS)

Comment: This fixed the problem instantly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that is user friendly there is a tool called system-config-samba that you can get from the software manager.

Once you have this downloaded you can see which folders are shared, their permissions and if they are visible. At least one folder must be visible in order for a Windows machine to see it on the network.

Comment: Doesn't work - crashes.