# how to configure samba file server for sharing between ubuntu pc's

Tags: server, samba, webserver

I want to share one ubuntu desktop to different ubuntu desktop. I want to share files, folders and printer as well.
Please suggest me the right procedure to share above thing between ubuntu users.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I have enhanced my answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/236746/how-to-turn-on-network-discovery-and-share-between-computers-with-samba to include more information regarding your question. It should help you share between Ubuntu computers and Ubuntu and Windows computers.

Comment: If you only want to share between non Windows computers, the preferred way is not to use samba, but CUPS for printer and nfs for file sharing.