# Ubuntu doesn't appear on network discovery when connected over Ethernet

Tags: networking, windows, lan

I am trying and failing to establish a wired network between a PC running Windows 8.1 and another running Ubuntu 14.04. Both the computers are connected to a the same LAN via a Switch.

While I am able to wirelessly network between these machines, neither machines appear on Windows nor Ubuntu network discovery; when connected via Ethernet. And it seems to be completely inaccessible. I am seeking to transfer large files back and forth between both machines regularly, so WiFi isn't really sufficient.

My Windows machine and Macbook Pro running OSX communicate fine via ethernet using the same switch and cables, so the problem does not appear to be anything to do with the hardware in question.

I realize I'm not being terribly specific, but I really don't know what on earth I'm doing wrong. I'm still quite a new Linux user, so please forgive me if I've missed something ridiculously obvious. If any specific hardware or other information is required I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: Are you saying that you can access via WiFi but no via LAN??? also, check with this is helping you? [**How to turn on Network Discovery and Share between computers with Samba**](http://askubuntu.com/a/236751/179042)

Comment: Does Windwoes have its firewall enabled on the LAN?

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that Samba share isnt installed on your linux box. Neither are the corresponding client dependencies installed of it. Samba (smb) is required in order to share files with windows and other OSes through smb protocol on your private network.

Maybe you are missing the samba client library too, the following post might help there:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide
or this:
https://goo.gl/mZT0ew

Comment: Actually Samba share is installed on my linux machine, although I'm not sure about the client dependencies. I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

How is configured the network on Ubuntu ? with network-manager ?

You can check that the Ubuntu PC and the windows one are on the same network.

```
sudo apt-get install arp-scan
sudo arp-scan -I eth0 -l
```

this will give you a list of all IP on the LAN

Next, you can try to ping the windows pc

And finally check if the route are correct. Look at

```
ip route
```

Check your firewall too

Comment: Ok, after entering the terminal command "sudo arp-scan -I eth0 -l" the termianl spat this :ioctl: Cannot assign requested address
WARNING: Could not obtain IP address for interface eth0. Using 0.0.0.0 for
the source address, which is probably not what you want.
Either configure eth0 with an IP address, or manually specify the address
with the --arpspa option.
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
ERROR: Could not obtain interface IP address and netmask
ERROR: pcap_lookupnet: eth0: no IPv4 address assigned

Comment: so problem solved. You don't have an IP setup for your eth0 interface. Check your network setup. Are you using IPv6 ?

Comment: Forgive my woeful ignorance, but I actually do not know, nor do I know how I find that out. Assuming I do, how do I go about setting up an IP address for eth0?

Comment: look at the double arrow icon on top right or the wifi icon. it's network manager applet. configure your eth0 to use dhcp

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm using Gnome. Anyway, edited the connection under Network Connections to "Automatic (DHCP)" under both the IPv4 and IPv5 tabs. I... don't quite know what I'm supposed to do after that, if anything.