# Linux to Linux Communication

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I know there is a solution out there somewhere but I just can't find it because I am just completely over my head.

I am working in a government controlled university lab that is air gapped. There is no wifi in the room and we have a 16 port switch that all computers connect to via ethernet.

Right now, all the computers connected to the switch are Windows and have no problem sending files over the network. When a new computer connects to the node they just need to "Map a Network Drive" and voila they can access a folder on the network.

I've been asked to do the exact same thing with Ubuntu Machines. I have 2 Machines (fresh installs) both with Ubuntu 20.04 and when I connect to the local network with ethernet cables both computers say that wired connection failed.

Typing ifconfig on both computers produces enp0s25 (or similar) and lo (wireless is disabled so no w:) but neither of them list a valid ip address.

I've tried finding tutorials all over the internet and I can't find something that works. I'm probably looking up the wrong thing. Can anyone help me?

Is this related question the answer to my problem?
[Ubuntu doesn't appear on network discovery when connected over Ethernet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626437/ubuntu-doesnt-appear-on-network-discovery-when-connected-over-ethernet#comment889038_626448)

Comment: Have you dropped by to see the network admin? Ubuntu out-of-the-box will try to detect a DHCP server, and then ask it for an IP address. Perhaps your network is static (no DHCP server) or has some unusual configuration. There are other possibilities. The network admin should know the answer about how their network was set up.

Comment: Once you know how your network is configured, feed that configuration data into your Netplan config ([examples](https://netplan.io/examples/)). That should get you an IP address and the ability to ping other machines on your network.

Comment: @user535733 I will check in with the network admin on Monday and get back to you thanks.

Comment: Just noticed that I never replied to this. I was able to get this to work using Samba. Thanks for all your replies.